# iPad Ad hoc version not run on the device

Tags: xcode4, certificate, ipad-2, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm facing a problem when running the AdHoc distribution app, I've developed an application and test it using development certificate on real device, running successfully, but when produce the adHoc and send it to my client to test it, the application installed successfully but does not run, where is the problem in this case?

the application using large image file (about 3-5 MB each image, but the number of the image is small, about 5-6 image) how can it run on the development certificate ?

**Solution:**

It seems that the tested ad hoc device was using a 3.4 ios version, and the app was developed for ios 5 and was contain some feature of the ios 5, so it was crashing every time the app run.

thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the tested ad hoc device was using a 3.4 ios version, and the app was developed for ios 5 and was contain some feature of the ios 5, so it was crashing every time the app run.